# Control Charts in Python Error

Tags: pandas, charts, error-handling, controls

I am trying to implement a Shewhart control chart on multiple variables, after looking up packages in Python to implement this I came across SPC and controlcharts. Both are failing to load when code :

```
pip install spc
pip install controlchart
```

both come with error code:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xdg2j1zr\spcchart\

All my packages are up to date and I am fearful the age of SPC/ ControlChart are preventing the installation. I am new to python and any help would be appreciated about what error code 1 indicates and where I can find control charts.

Comment: Hi Grady R, welcome on SO. I hope you can find you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: Anybody have any other ideas? Make my job a lot easier if I could find a way for the package to work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this command

```
pip install python-controlchart
```

For the second command
There is another package

```
pip install pyspc
```